# Error Running Bulk Metric create script in command manager Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I'm trying to run the script below in the command manager, and I'm getting the error messages below. The script is supposed to bulk create a bunch of metrics from facts in another folder. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing. I'm new to running scripts in command manager.

```
Script:

//list all metrics in the project 
  String sProjectName = "ProjectName";
  String sFactFolder = "\Schema Objects\Facts\FolderName";
  String sMetricFolder = "\Public Objects\Metrics\BulkTest";
  ResultSet oFacts = executeCapture("LIST ALL FACTS IN FOLDER '" + sFactFolder + "' FOR PROJECT '" + sProjectName + "';"); 
  oFacts.moveFirst();  
  while (!oFacts.isEof() )
  {
   //get name and path of this metric to list properties
   String sFactName = oFacts.getFieldValueString(DisplayPropertyEnum.NAME);       
   //get properties of each metric
   EXECUTE("CREATE METRIC "" + sFactName + "" IN FOLDER "" + sMetricFolder + "" EXPRESSION 'sum([" + sFactName + "])' ON PROJECT "" + sProjectName + "";");
     oFacts.moveNext();
   }


Errors:

Syntax error at line '2', column '4'. Expected: ADD, ALTER, APPLY, APPEND, ACTIVATE, BULKSAVEBEGINS, BULKSAVEENDS, CLEAR, CONNECT, CREATE, DEACTIVATE, DELETE, DISCONNECT, DISABLE, ENABLE, GET, GRANT, IDLE, IMPORT, INVALIDATE, KILL, LIST, LOAD, LOG, PUBLISH, PURGE, REGISTER, REMOVE, REPLACE, RESTART, RESUME, REVOKE, RUN, SEND, SET, START, STOP, TAKE OWNERSHIP, TRIGGER, UNLOAD, UNLOCK, UNREGISTER, UPDATE, VALIDATE, RESET, LOCK, EXECUTE, EXPIRE
Task(s) execution completed with errors.
Execution Time: 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re running that directly in Command Manager, it will fail, because it’s Java. You’ll need to create a procedure with that code, and call the procedure from Command Manager. The documentation should cover that process I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use Procedure and type (do not paste the code) that code in there.
Also, change the Execute command as below.

```
EXECUTE("CREATE METRIC '" + sFactName + 
        "' IN FOLDER '" + sMetricFolder + 
        "' EXPRESSION 'sum([" + sFactName + "])' ON PROJECT '" + sProjectName + "';");
oFacts.moveNext();
```

It works.